# Crashes not showing up in Firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to transition my iOS app from Crashlytics to Firebase, since Crashlytics is going to be shut down in a month. I went through the steps described here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk

It all looked great until I tried my first test distribution. I added a piece of code that would crash the app on a button tap to test that I get the crashes from distributed apps. However, it didn't work. The app crashes, but I see no crash reports. I do see that Crash-free users percentage is going down though. So something is getting registered, but the actual crashes are not there.

My fists couple of test distributions were missing DSYMs. And under DSYMs tab I could even see the crash count. However, when I did upload the DSYMs the crashes still didn't appear.

Now I'm using a script that does the DSYM upload on archive, but crashes are not showing up still.

When I do a build using Xcode and force crash everything works as expected. It's only the distributed AdHoc builds don't show any crashes in the portal.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue if you find any solution than comment please

Comment: please, see my answer below about disabling bitcode

Comment: @HarshilKotecha, please let me know if that fixes it, cause if it doesn't I might have other ideas :)

Comment: i had the same issue, i tried a lots of things and check but i did not still get the any crashes on the crash log of firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boom, after hours of trying and searching.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2901

Disabling bitcode for AdHoc builds fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your forced crash didn't crash, crashed before you wanted it to, or you're experiencing some other issue with Crashlytics, you can enable Crashlytics debug logging to track down the problem.

To enable debug logging on your development device, specify the following command line argument in Xcode:

**Crashlytics 3.11.1+**

```
-FIRDebugEnabled
```

**Previous versions**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize Firebase service.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
    return true
}
```